# Learning Perl, One-Liner behaves differently

Tags: perl

**UPDATE**

As pointed out in the answer, this question really has to do with Scalar versus List Context in Perl.

## ## ## ##

I am learning perl via self-taught crash course (primarily with the Llama book and the web). In attempting some byte swap code, I have found a one liner I do not understand completely. A comment in the script explains what I think is happening in the one-liner.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
#
# Script to print byte-swapped hex values
#

use 5.010;
use warnings;
use strict;

# NOTE: I realize I could use a single variable 'data', but the x- y- z- prefixes may help in
# identification (for clarity) in the code for this SO question.
my $xData;
my $yData;
my $zData;

for ( my $ijk = 998; $ijk < 1001; $ijk++ )
{
  printf ( "\n%4d is hex " . (sprintf "0x%04X", $ijk) . "\n", $ijk );

  # with byte swap
  say "These numbers (bytes swapped) should match...";

  # do sprintf, match pattern and store to ($1)($2), now reverse them into ($2)($1). 
  # BindOp leaves $_ alone, match stuffs $_ & is then used as input for reverse, prints.
  say reverse ((sprintf "%04X", $ijk) =~ /(..)(..)/) ;        # from perlmonks' webpage

  $yData = (reverse ((sprintf "%04X", $ijk) =~ /(..)(..)/) );
  say $yData;                         # does NOT match

  $xData = sprintf "%04X", $ijk;
  $xData =~ s/(..)(..)/$2$1/ ;
  say $xData;                         # does match

  $_ = sprintf "%04X", $ijk;
  /(..)(..)/;
  $zData = $2 . $1 ;
  say $zData;                         # does match
}

exit 0;
```

OUTPUT:

> 998 is hex 0x03E6 These numbers (bytes swapped) should match... 
>   E603 
>   6E30 
>   E603 
>   E603
>
> 999 is hex 0x03E7 These numbers (bytes swapped) should match... 
>   E703
>   7E30 
>   E703 
>   E703
>
> 1000 is hex 0x03E8 These numbers (bytes swapped) should match... 
>   E803
>   8E30 
>   E803 
>   E803

Why does the one liner work, and why doesn't the `$yData` perform the same way? I'm pretty sure I understand why `$xData` and `$zData` work, but I would expect `$yData` to be the closest equivalent non-one-liner. What is the closest equivalent non-one-liner and why? Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: `for ( my $ijk = 998; $ijk < 1001; $ijk++ )` is better written `for my $ijk ( 998 .. 1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reverse` in your print (`say`) statement comes in the list context, while when assigned to `$yData` the context is scalar.  This function (may) behave considerably differently based on the context.

From `perldoc -f reverse`

> reverse LIST
>                  In list context, returns a list value consisting of the elements of LIST in the opposite order.  In scalar context, concatenates the elements of LIST and returns a string value with all characters in the opposite order.

In this case this produces different results.

---

When called in list context, it swaps the (two) input bytes, keeping each byte intact (represented by two hexadecimal digits matched in a group).   When called in scalar context, it joins the input and returns a character string, running in the opposite order. Taken to represent a hex number this would have each byte changed.

Comment: I verified this by changing `$yData` to `@yData` and it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Another helpful fact is that `say` expects a list (see perldoc), hence the list context which makes reverse work the way it does in the one-liner.

Comment: @zdim: I think you're missing the real problem. You say *"In this case this produces different results."* but you haven't said *why*. It's nothing to do with the context of the call to `reverse`

Comment: @Borodin  I've given this time but I still don't quite understand.  I added an explanation, if you mean that that was missing.  If not, I would appreciate it if you could explain..